# Declaring Instant of class in view Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following models in my models.py

```
class Grade(models.Model):
    grade = models.IntegerField()

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    grade = models.ForeignKey(Grade)
    rollno = models.BigIntegerField()
```

I want to do the post method in the view.py for the class Student.

When it is without the foreign key it is very simple as below;

```
class RegisterStudent(generics.ListAPIView):
    '''
    GET student/
    POST student/
    '''
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer


        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

            a_site = Student.objects.create(
            name=request.data["name"],
            grade=request.data["grade"],
            rollno=request.data["rollno"],
            )
            return Response(
                data=StudentSerializer(a_site).data,
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            )
```

But when I use the foreignkey method, I am not sure how to do it for grade in student.

And this is how I am doing for grade:

```
class RegisterGrade(generics.ListAPIView):
    '''
    GET grade/
    POST grade/
    '''
    queryset = Grade.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GradeSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        a_site = Grade.objects.create(
            grade=request.data["grade"],
        )
        return Response(
            data=GradeSerializer(a_site).data,
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        )
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: if `a_site` is your `Grade` object, just initialise the student as before, with `Student.objects.create`, but pass `grade = a_site` as a keyword argument alongside the other fields

Comment: Really you're doing far too much work here. DRF will do all this for you, including the nesting.

Comment: Hey Daniel, could you please explain me what you mean. I'd really like to reduce the work.

Answer (score 0):

Just get or create `Grade` and use it when creating a `Student`

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    grade, created = Grade.objects.get_or_create(
        grade=int(request.data["grade"]),
    )
    student = Student.objects.create(
        name=request.data["name"],
        grade=grade,
        rollno=request.data["rollno"],
    )
    return Response(
        data=StudentSerializer(student).data,
        status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
    )
```

Here you check if `Grade` already exists and if it does you have grade from database if not it creates a new `Grade`.Then you create a Student with a `grade`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But the attributes of grade in model grade is coming as an int rather than char.

Comment: Just convert it to int according to my chances above.